# awk: Insert line after comments and imports in source file

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I have bunch of source files with very usual structure: some comments in header, some (optional) imports, and then source code, e.g.:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  settings
//
//  Created by Mikhail Igonin on 14/06/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Mikhail Igonin. All rights reserved.
// 


import UIKit
import Fabric
import Crashlytics


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    //Other comment
}
```

I need to add another import after comments and import block. So regex to match beginning of this file should look like this:

```
(([\n\s]*)((\/\/.*\n)|(import.*\n)))+
```

And looks like this regex is ok: https://www.regextester.com/index.php?fam=106706

Now I'm trying to inset new import with `awk` and `gensub`:

```
gawk -v RS='^$' '{$0=gensub(/(([\n\s]*)((\/\/.*\n)|(import.*\n)))+/,"\\1\\2\nimport NEW_IMPORT\n\\2",1)}1' test.swift
```

However it doesn't work and my regex match all file:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  settings
//
//  Created by Mikhail Igonin on 14/06/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Mikhail Igonin. All rights reserved.
//


import UIKit
import Fabric
import Crashlytics


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

}

import NEW_IMPORT
```

What's my mistake? Looks like `.*` works incorrect and match all file. I've tried to mark it as lazy (`.*?`) but without success also.

PS Solutions without awk or gensub would be also useful.

Comment: (1) Have you tried printing the records (i.e., `$0` values) that you're getting?  ```RS='^$'``` might get you each stanza (block of non-blank lines) as a record, so the comments will be the first record, the imports will be the second record, and you'll never see both at the same time. (2) You might be better off using `awk` as a state machine rather than trying to do a multi-line regex.

Comment: The tester is set to `javascript`, btw, not sure that's what awk uses ... switching it to PCRE doesn't give a match ...

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to assume that `.` (as in `.*`) doesn't match a newline in `awk`: it does. That's different from `sed`, `grep`, `perl`, `javascript`, etc. (Think of `awk` regexps as always greedy and with the `//s` flag always on).

Setting `RS` to `^$` will cause `awk` to slurp the whole file as a single record, and then the `\/\/.*\n` pattern will match from the first `//` up to the last newline in the file; the `import.*\n` branch won't even be considered.

There are probably smarter ways to do it, but this will insert the `import NEW_IMPORT` line after the first run of `import` lines from your file:

```
awk '!e&&/^import/,e=!/^import/{if(e)print "import NEW_IMPORT"}1' test.swift
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most efficient for large files, but inserts the new import line after the LAST `import ...` statement found:

```
tac file | awk '/^import/ && !I {I = 1; print "import New_IMPORT"} 1' | tac
```

Comment: I would hope source code files are **not** that large!